# Developing Lightning Components for Visualforce Pages with Salesforce Classic

Tags: visualforce, lightning-aura-components, lightning-experience, salesforce-classic

I am aware of the ability to host lightning components in Visualforce pages.
Is it possible to develop and deploy lightning components in Visualforce Pages for Org which doesn't have Lightning Experience enabled ?

What are the possible issues/limitation of this approach ?
I know there could be some limitations around what ui components or events can be used etc.

Any insight on this would be very helpful.

Answer (score 4):

With the use of Lightning Out we can definitely build Lightning components that be accessed inside Salesforce (embed in Visualforce, not an `iframe`) or even outside of Salesforce.

I think most obvious issue with Authentication, as components run outside of Salesforce. So, to use it we may need to setup `Connected App` with OAuth.

2nd thing, could be the navigation where it needs to be handled where navigation is happening, whether inside Lightning Context or Standard Classic UI. We may need to handle navigation through Javascript rather than using `PageReference`.

3rd thing, maintaining the styling with Classic UI and Lightning Components.

For more information, refer [Lightning Out Considerations and Limitations](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/lightning_out_considerations.htm)